# Is "a few street away" a grammatically acceptable idiomatic expression in some dialect of UK English?

Tags: british-english

I am an American and I am reading a book titled *Bloodmage* by a British author named Stephen Aryan.
He uses expressions I was previously unfamiliar with, such as "sat" instead of "sitting" (i.e., "sat at the table were three men") and "stood" instead of "standing."  I originally thought these were grammatically incorrect, but have since learned that they are a "standard" part of a northern English dialect.

Now I have come across a sentence in the book that begins with "A few street away..." This again seemed liked an obvious typo, but I checked online and found several edited British news articles that use the same expression (among the news sources were "Bristol Post" and "Sunday Express").
Is this also another "standard" or informal idiom of a dialect from northern England? If so, why is it used in place of "a few streets away"?

Comment: I'm British and am quite familiar with *a few streets away* but have never heard it rendered as singular. Using past participle *sat*, instead of present *sitting*, is widespread among northerners in Britain - both east and west of the Pennines. Though I don't think it would have enough merit to be included as part of a Northern British Standard. Paradoxically they will often use the present *cooking* where they need the past *cooked*. So in Manchester or Leeds, it would be perfectly normal to hear, *There I was sat at the table, when the waitress asked me how I wanted my steak cooking*.

Comment: These forms are not as common in the south of England, and the West Country (Bristol). But people move around, and their appearance in newspapers is as much a reflection of who wrote the report, as anything. But you would be unlikely to find them in more serious newspapers such as The Times, The Telegraph or The Guardian.

Comment: I do not hesitate to say that _a few street away_ is a typo.

Comment: @WS2 Might it be a poorly executed attempt to write in dialect?  The author's bio says he is from the Midlands which really should put him close enough to be familiar with a northern cadence and use.

Comment: @Icy Ah, well if he's a Brummie (Birmingham) he may say *sat* for *sitting*. I'm not quite sure if they do or not. Perhaps there is a Midlander around who can help us.

Comment: I've lived across Wales, south-western England and the Midlands in my time. "Sat" doesn't jar one bit to my ears - so much so that I wouldn't even recognise it as regional in any way.

Comment: @ProfYaffle, agreed.  These past 50 years, my ears have been tuned to "I was sat/stood" after being admonished at high school for using 'Yorkshire-isms', and I've noticed it more and more on UK radio and TV, often by speakers who don't sound at all northern.  I suspect it's spreading.

Comment: @WS2 Agree totally (!!!) I'd never thought of the grammaticality or otherwise of 'How do you want it cooking?' / 'He will want it painting' / 'Do you want it saving?' etc. I'd say the construction is quite acceptable hereabouts (the NW).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is predicated on a typo.

Answer (score 2):

I'm from the North East of England, so a Geordie, not a Brummie, that's the West Midlands of England.

The first is a typo, it should be a few streets away. Not an attempt to write in dialect.

Stephen

Comment: Hello, Stephen. I'd agree, but unsubstantiated answers are not what is required on ELU – they so easily generate into 'Well, that's what _I_ think, anyway'. This is a 'comment' (for which you need a bit more 'rep').

Comment: @Edwin This answer appears to be from the author of the book.